# Firebase queryEqualToValue with childKey

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query data in my Firebase database using:

```
queryEqual(toValue: Any?, childKey: String?)
```

My database structure:

```
Schools {
    testUID1 {
        schoolNameLC: test school 1
    }
}
```

My query is:

```
databaseReference.child("Schools").queryEqual(toValue: "test school 1", childKey: "schoolNameLC").observe(.value) { (snap) in
        print(snap)
    }
```

This query prints out `null` and I can't quite get it to work. Because of the way my app is set up, I don't know that the key `schoolNameLC` has a value `testSchool1` under the parent key of `testUID1`. All I want to do is search through the `Schools` in my database and return anything with a `schoolNameLC` value of `test school 1`.

Comment: try `databaseReference.child("Schools").queryOrderedByChild("schoolNameLC").queryEqualToValue(test school 1).observe(.value) { (snap) in
        print(snap.value)
    }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two-parameter `queryEqualToValue:childKey:` (and its brethren `queryStartingAtValue:childKey:` and `queryEndingAtValue:childKey:`) are unfortunately some of the most misunderstood methods in the Firebase Database API.

To order by a child and then filter on a value of that child, you have to call `queryOrderedByChild().queryEqualToValue()`. So as @ElCaptainV2.0 said:

```
databaseReference.child("Schools")
    .queryOrderedByChild("scho‌​olNameLC")
    .queryEqua‌​lToValue("test school 1")
```

You only should use the `childKey:` parameter if you **also** want to start at a specific key in all nodes that have the same matching `test school 1` value. This overload is really mostly useful when you're trying to paginate/endless scroll results.