# FirebaseDatabase - Filter by property value and sort by a different property value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some Firebase data structured like:

```
root {
    uid0 {
        date: someDateValue
        flag: true
    }
    uid1 {
        date: anotherDateValue
        flag: false
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get all `root`'s children that have `flag` set to true, and order them by their `date` value.

Is this possible?

I thought maybe combining an ordered query with an equal query would work. The following query doesn't produce the results I expect.

```
return ref
    .child("root")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "date")
    .queryEqual(toValue: false, childKey: "flag")
```

I don't believe this question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421387/firebase-queryequaltovalue-with-childkey). I am looking to order by and filter by *different* properties, while that question is ordering and filtering by the *same* property, which is actually possible.

Comment: A Firebase Database query can only contain one order-by call. So you can't filter on one property and sort on another. The `childKey` argument does not serve that need either. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421387/firebase-queryequaltovalue-with-childkey

Comment: It may be possible to combine the two values you want to filter/order on, into a single property and then order/filter on that. See my answer here for an example: ;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: I saw your answer, and although it may work, I really dislike the idea of combining properties (event if it is automated). It just doesn't feel correct. What I ended up doing was restructuring my data to include two root nodes (`root`, and `rootFlag`) where `rootFlag` would store the `uid<x>` nodes with `flag` set to true.

Comment: I also don't think this is a duplicate question (I edited the question).

Comment: The way your code snippet tries to use `childKey` is wrong and will never allow you to use two properties. The question I marked as a duplicate explains why.